# Parsing out text after final "_"

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, parsing, substr

I'm a SQL Newbie trying to solve a problem.  I need to parse out a name from a field, but the field is not static, the length can vary.  **I always need the last text field after the final** `_`

For example:

```
aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd   I need to return ddd
aaa_bbb_ccc       I need to return ccc
```

I've been struggling using both `regexp` and `substr`.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get this done ?   Thank you in advance !

DB is Oracle in case there are specific functions that I'm not aware of.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show some code of your attempts?

Comment: have you tried anything like, `regexp_substr('aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd','[^_]*$')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use INSTR and SUBSTR together to get what you want:

```
strLast_name := SUBSTR(SOME_FIELD, INSTR(SOME_FIELD, '_', -1)+1);
```

will return 'ddd' if `SOME_FIELD` contains 'aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd`.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle, the [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm) function should provide what you need

The regex would be something like `[^_]+$` (1 or more none underscore char at the end of the string)

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this problem in 2 ways:

**INPUT test table:**

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255) 
);

select * from PERSONS;
insert into PERSONS(PersonID,LastName,FirstName,Address,City) values (1,'a_rbit_aaa',null,null,null);
insert into PERSONS(PersonID,LastName,FirstName,Address,City) values (2,'t_obt_bbb',null,null,null);
insert into PERSONS(PersonID,LastName,FirstName,Address,City) values (3,'t_co_mp_ccc',null,null,null);
insert into PERSONS(PersonID,LastName,FirstName,Address,City) values (4,'t_d_or_ddd',null,null,null);
insert into PERSONS(PersonID,LastName,FirstName,Address,City) values (5,'cramp_123',null,null,null);
insert into PERSONS(PersonID,LastName,FirstName,Address,City) values (6,'p_o_d_abc',null,null,null);
insert into PERSONS(PersonID,LastName,FirstName,Address,City) values (7,'123_abc_uvw_xyz',null,null,null);

commit;
```

**1) The substring approach:**

This is better in your case since we do not need to extract a pattern and/or use backreferences and manipulate a string. A regex approach will be slow down your query and consumes more memory/cpu.

```
select substr(lastname, Instr(lastname, '_',-1) +1)from PERSONS;
```

result:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
123
abc
xyz
```

**2) The regex approach:**

Just for learning purpose and fun, let me introduce the regex approach (not necessary for your specific case), you can choose to extract the part that you need from your string using `regex_substr` or do it the other way around: remove everything that is not required in your string.

```
select regexp_substr(lastname, '[^_]+$')from PERSONS; --the regex will fetch only the non underscore characters at the end of the string
```

or

```
select regexp_replace(lastname, '^(:?[^_]*_)*', '')from PERSONS; --remove every block of non underscore char followed by one underscore, till will keep only the last non underscore part as is
```

for both, result:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd
123
abc
xyz
```

Comment: Thanks Everyone !!   I was monitoring my email instead of the thread directly so sorry for my late response.   Originally - I had this CASE WHEN regexp_SUBSTR(GN.business_unit,'[^_]+',1,3) = 'G' Then 'GOLD'  But I've updated my query with the suggestions above and It's working as needed.  Thanks  a lot !